# Unable to send data from one Client to another in socket.io Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have two clients which can interchange some data over socket.io. I also have a server. What i need to do is i want to send data from client 1 to client 2 over a socket and i am unable to figure out that how i can achieve it.Please note that client 1 and client 2 are different html pages.

**Server.JS**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var ip=process.env.IP||"192.168.1.5";
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
server.listen(port,ip, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d ', port);
});
app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/test.html'));
})
app.get('/index1', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/test1.html'));
})

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('broadcast', function (message) {
            console.log(message);




            socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
            });
            console.log("connected");

 });
```

**Client1.JS**

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script >
var socket = io.connect();
socket.emit('broadcast',"Broadcasting Message");
socket.on('message', function (data) {

     alert(data)
});
 </script>
  </body>
```

**Client2.JS**

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script >
var socket = io.connect();


socket.on('message', function (data) {

     alert(data)
    //socket.emit('message',"Hello world");
});
 </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is what I did on my local and you may change it by your needs.

> server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.on('broadcast', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
        });
        console.log("connected");
```

});

> client1.js

```
var socket = io.connect('ws://127.0.0.1');
socket.emit('broadcast',"Broadcasting Message");
socket.on('message', function (data) {
     $('#client1').html(data);
});
```

> client2.js

```
 var socket = io.connect('ws://127.0.0.1');
 socket.on('message', function (data) {
     $('#client2').html(data);
});
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="client1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="client2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div> <h1> CLIENT 1 </h1><div id="client1"></div></div>
        <div> <h1> CLIENT 2 </h1><div id="client2"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On a termminal after you run, `node server.js` and reload your page, you will see client2 will have `Broadcasting message` html appended

Comment: thanks let me check it at my end the code is almost the same i think i may have been missing the url in my code

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to pass the URL to the server when instantiating WS on the client side... for example `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');`

On the server side, each WS connection with each client is a unique instance. That is to say that for this purpose you must be deliberate about which WS connection you target when emitting events.

The first thing to solve is how to associate WS connection instances with specific clients. The answer to this is to use a map/dictionary/plain ol' javascript object with some sort of unique client identifier as the key and the instance of the WS connection as the value. Pseudo-code:

```
let connections = { 'client1': WSinstance, 'client2': WSinstance };
```

You would add to this object every time you create a new WS instance. Assuming you have a way to uniquely identify a client and that is stored in the variable `clientId`, you could do the following:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  connections[clientId] = socket;
}
```

Now if you want to emit a message to just client1 you can use the WS instance associated with them by grabbing it from the object `connections.client1` or if you want to target client2 `connections.client2`

Comment: Hi @rdgd Thanks for reply by seeing your answer i think what you are trying to say is that i want to send message from my server to each and every client but what i need to do is to send message from client 1 to client 2 ! I will have to use server as a middle man here i completely understand your answer!

Comment: he is using socket.io, and this helps you to broadcast emit messages through all socket clients. `socket.broadcast.emit()` I don't see anything wrong with the code to be honest and it should work. but it looks like there is something else is missing and full code would help more.

Comment: No problem Danish. I am attempting to answer your question, sending from client1 to client2, and yes you would need to use your server as the middleman in this equation unless you are using WebRTC or some such. Not sure why I've been downvoted... My answer presumes that he wants to target x client from y client, not that he wants to broadcast all messages to all clients. This works conceptually, as I have implemented a similar design many times.

Comment: @guyfawkes thanks for reply actually this is my full code!! i must have been missing some thing here the rest of the code include the addition of socket.io script on both the server and client scripts! i am trying to do this on a very basic level!

Comment: @Danish are you using same client.js from your server or externally from cdn or somewhere else. I will try to create on my local to see if is there anything else

Comment: I believe he is missing the connection string/url when instantiating on the client-side. @Danish I updated my answer which I hope will solve the problem for you.

Comment: can you update your post with full code. like connection strings etc. which IP and port you are using to connect etc.

Comment: @rdgd if we have deployed the socket.io on same server then i dont think we have to mention the url? please correct me if i am wrong! i am  a little newbie here

Comment: @guyfawkes please wait i am updating the code Thanks

Comment: I believe you do need to pass the URL. It appears to be the one required argument: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socketopen

Comment: Also, check your browser's console... are there any errors there that you can post?

Comment: @rdgd thanks i understand your point but without the url it works for one client if i just omit the other client and send the data from client to server it receive the message however i will add the url and see it something is different thanks